# i cant sum the numbers (python)

Tags: python, function, sum

*Write a shell (text-based) program, called sum_num.py, that asks the user for a semicolon (;) separated list of numbers, and calculated the total. See the example below.*

```
a = str(raw_input("Enter semicolon separated list of integers:"))
b = a.split(";")
c = (a[0:])

print("the total is " + sum(c))

PS C:\Users\ssiva\Desktop> python sum_num.py
Enter semicolon separated list of integers: 3;10;4;23;211;3
The total is 254
```

Comment: What question are you trying to ask us?

Comment: how to get sum of numbers in the list.

Comment: Splitting a string gives you a list of strings.  Convert them to integers before sum.

Comment: Please read over this article from the stack overflow help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It's currently hard to tell what you're asking and what the current problem with your code is.

Comment: What is `b` even used for here? Looks like you have a logic issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will convert into integers and sum them

```
a=input()
b=a.split(';')
sum=0
for num in b:
     sum+=int(num)
print(sum)
```